# Nodejs mysql ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using [Node Mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/)

```
var values = []; //array with actual values
var sql = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updated_at = now()";

connection.query(sql, values, function() {

});
```

And I get an error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updated_at = now()
```

Meanwhile the same query works in mysql cli.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are not placing any value on the "values" array, and the INSERT expects two. You can check how the SQL got built with:

```
var query = connection.query(sql, values, function() {});
console.log(query.sql);
```